# How do I open :Rpreview in a seperate window?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, awesome-wm

I'm using awesome WM and every time I use :Rpreview (the T-Pope rails.vim plugin) it opens localhost on another tab where I've left my browser (chromium) open.  How can I make it open under the current tab in a new window?

Comment: linux with the archlinux distro